# Looking to rebuild .sorted and use to initialize a list

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a list of items I would like to sort. Now granted I could the `.sorted` right out of the box and it would work.. but trying to gain a deeper understanding.. I am wondering why I can't get my own custom sort function to work..

This is my current attempt.

```
extension Array where Element == Coin {
    func sortByRank(first: Element, second: Element) -> Bool {
     first.rank < second.rank
    }
}
```

But I can't call that in the list initializer because of the parameters that need to be passed in.. I also created one that accepted a closure but got stuck at how to implement..

```
extension Array where Element == Coin {
    func sortByRank(closure: (Element, Element) -> Bool) {
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are already defining the Element and the property that will sort your collection there is no need to pass anything to your method. All you would need is a bool to define if it should be in ascending order or not:

---

```
extension Array where Element == Coin {
    func sortByRank(ascending: Bool = true) -> [Element] {
        sorted(by: { ascending ? $0.rank < $1.rank : $0.rank > $1.rank })
    }
}
```

---

```
struct Coin {
    let rank: Int
}
```

---

```
let ascending = [Coin(rank: 5),Coin(rank: 3),Coin(rank: 4)].sortByRank()
let descending =  [Coin(rank: 5),Coin(rank: 3),Coin(rank: 4)].sortByRank(ascending: false)
ascending   // [{rank 3}, {rank 4}, {rank 5}]
descending  // [{rank 5}, {rank 4}, {rank 3}]
```

---

What I would suggest is to implement a generic sorted method that would take a predicate that would allow you to pass a KeyPath to your method:

```
extension Sequence {
    func sorted<T: Comparable>(_ predicate: (Element) -> T, by areInIncreasingOrder: ((T,T)-> Bool) = (<)) -> [Element] {
        sorted(by: { areInIncreasingOrder(predicate($0), predicate($1)) })
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
let coins = [Coin(rank: 5),Coin(rank: 3),Coin(rank: 4)]
let ascending = coins.sorted(\.rank)
let descending =  coins.sorted(\.rank, by: >)
ascending   // [{rank 3}, {rank 4}, {rank 5}]
descending  // [{rank 5}, {rank 4}, {rank 3}]
```

And the mutating version (sort) of it:

```
extension MutableCollection where Self: RandomAccessCollection {
    mutating func sort<T: Comparable>(_ predicate: (Element) -> T, by areInIncreasingOrder: ((T,T)-> Bool) = (<))  {
        sort(by: { areInIncreasingOrder(predicate($0), predicate($1)) })
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
var coins = [Coin(rank: 5),Coin(rank: 3),Coin(rank: 4)]
coins.sort(\.rank)
coins       // [{rank 3}, {rank 4}, {rank 5}]
coins.sort(\.rank, by: >)
coins   // [{rank 5}, {rank 4}, {rank 3}]
```